# How to assign ad account to business manager account using facebook ads API?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I am implementing functionality to Claiming ad accounts using Facebook ads API & I found their following documentation link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/assets/v2.9

And I have prepared & made API call accordingly but its not working and returning following error.

"(#275) Cannot determine the target object for this request. Currently supported objects include ad account, business account and associated objects."

Here is the API call I am using.

```
curl \
-F "adaccount_id=act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>" \
-F "access_type=OWNER" \
-F "access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/{API_VERSION}/{BUSINESS_ID}/adaccounts"
```

I have passed valid business id, adaccount id & access token in my API call.

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: the request looks fine for this actually. I tested using Business Manager and it's using the same thing, but with v2.8. As this is the correct request, and it's not working, please file a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs
You can privately share the IDs and access token also so we can verify that is not the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have submitted a bug on FB regarding the same. Here is the link for it.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1846308019025647/

Comment: You should privately submit on the thread the exact call you're making including the business ID and account ID as then they'll have all the information required to debug this